# run the startUp method at the deploy a web service

Tags: java, apache, web-services, tomcat, apache-axis

I try to execute the startUp method when i deploy my web services, but doesn`t work.

I'm using:

> windows 7
>
> tomcat 8.0.30
>
> axis2 1.7.0

I've tryed to deploy my service as a pojo service also i try generating the *.aar and placing it in:

> apache-tomcat-8.0.30\webapps\axis2\WEB-INF\services
>   but when i run the tomcat, and deploy this and other services, the startUp method dont launch. 
>   this is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContext;
import org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService;
import org.apache.axis2.engine.ServiceLifeCycle;

public class Login implements ServiceLifeCycle{

    static String IPprop = "";
    static String rutaDB = "C:/resources/users_DB.txt";
    static String rutaUddiXml = "C:/resources/uddi.xml";
    static String rutaIP = "C:/resources/ip.txt";
    static boolean registrado=false;
    static String comp ="";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        IP();
        String nombreServicio = "Login";
        String rutaServicio = "http://"+ IPprop +":8080/axis2/services/Login";
        SimplePublishPortable spp = new SimplePublishPortable(rutaUddiXml);
        spp.publish(nombreServicio, rutaServicio);
        System.out.println("te registraste");
    }

    public static void createUser(String user, String pass) {
        interacFich("crea", user, pass);
    }

    public static String loginAccess(String user, String pass) {
        return interacFich("login", user, pass);
    }

    public static String runComprobation(){
        return "deployed service" + comp;
    } 

    public static String regComprobation(){
        if(registrado==true){
            return "registered";
        }
        else{
            return "failed";
        }
    }

    private static String getToken() {
        String cadenaAleatoria = "";

        int i = 0;
        while (i < 10) {
            char c = (char) ((int) (Math.random() * 255 + 1));
            if ((c >= '0' && c <= '9') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')) {
                cadenaAleatoria += c;
                i++;
            }
        }
        return cadenaAleatoria;
    }

    private static String interacFich(String accion, String user, String pass) {
        String usuario = "";
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> usuarios = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

        File archivo = new File(rutaDB);

        // leer fichero y meterlo en el mapa
        if (archivo.exists() == false) {
            try {
                archivo.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(archivo))) {
                while (br.ready()) {
                    usuario = br.readLine();
                    String[] param = usuario.split("\\*");
                    usuarios.put(param[0], param[1]);

                }
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        switch (accion) {
        case "crea":
            usuarios.put(user + "-" + pass, getToken());

            try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(archivo))) {
                Set<String> keysUsuarios = usuarios.keySet();
                for (String k : keysUsuarios) {
                    bw.write(k + "*" + usuarios.get(k).toString());
                    bw.write("\n");

                }
                System.out.println("todo escrito");
                bw.close();

                return "el fichero se crea";
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        case "login":
            if (usuarios.containsKey(user + "-" + pass)) {
                return usuarios.get(user + "-" + pass);
            }
            return "User o pass erroneos";
        default:
            break;

        }

        return null;
    }

    private static void IP() {
        File archivo = new File(rutaIP);
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(archivo))) {
            br.readLine();
            IPprop = br.readLine();


    br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return;

}
@Override
public void startUp(ConfigurationContext arg0, AxisService arg1) {
    ///////////////
    //registrarse//
    ///////////////
    comp="entramos";
    IP();
    String nombreServicio = "Login";
    String rutaServicio = "http://"+ IPprop +":8080/axis2/services/Login";
    SimplePublishPortable spp = new SimplePublishPortable(rutaUddiXml);
    spp.publish(nombreServicio, rutaServicio);
    registrado=true;
}

@Override
public void shutDown(ConfigurationContext arg0, AxisService arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you created the *Service Definition* (services.xml) file, on which you describe your services?

I am referring to a file similar to the example in `Code Listing 3: The Service Definition File` in the following link (axis2 quick start):

https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/quickstartguide.html#services

Comment: yes, the services.xml is automatically generated when i do:  


"wsdl2java -uri serviceName.wsdl" ->  
"ant jar.server -ss -sp"


to generate the *.aar